# Can i just paste jtd as typescript type syntax?

Tags: typescript, ajv

Is JSON type definition (found no available tag btw), apart from extensions, always valid and unproblematic as typescript type syntax?<sup>1</sup>

I want to generate `.d.ts` for a parser module compiled from a jtd with ajv. Can I simply embed the JSON as a typescript, when generating one?

```
import type { JTDDataType } from 'ajv/dist/jtd';

type JTD = /* just directly paste json here */

export default function(json: string): JTDDataType<JTD> | undefined;
```

The plan would be to load the `.json` jtd file, validate it is proper jtd, check there is no `metadata` property, and then just paste it into the format seen above, and save it as `.d.ts`. `JTDDataType` is a [utility type from ajv](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html#utility-type-for-jtd-data-type), which converts a jtd schema type to the related valid types in typescript.

Security notes:

- I do not intend to load arbitrary jtd files from users, but only ones made by trusted developers
- the conversion is non-executable JSON to what I think is non-executable `.d.ts`, it can't suddenly execute code when something was overlooked

[related previous question (currently unanswered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66873188/generate-type-declaration-for-pre-compiled-jtd-validator-module)

---

1: Tbh, this could potentially be broader: Is JSON in general valid typescript type syntax? I at least can't immediately find a reason, why the following would fail:

```
type T = /* just paste any JSON here */
```

Therefore, maybe even the check for `metadata` is unnecessary, I can just paste and be fine.